# Docker Desktop Image creation failed

Tags: docker

I am using `Docker Desktop` and trying to create the client's `Docker images` in my local and get this error:

Any idea on how to resolve this?

[image]

Thanks,

Samridhi

Comment: check if you can browse the download link yourself in a browser

Comment: Yes Sumit, I can access the browser link, and if I run the curl command in Git bash that also works fine but it fails while building docker image

Comment: Have you checked Docker DNS settings?  i.e "dns": ["8.8.8.8"]. (Docker -> Settings -> Docker Engine)

Comment: Yes @MiguelMinoldo, it is in place

Comment: Is the Command Prompt open in admin mode?

Comment: yes @SumitUpadhyay

Comment: You can try Invoke-WebRequest with Powershell, instead of curl. It may work.

Comment: @VinayJadav, can you please elaborate a bit. Should I replace curl with Invoke-WebRequest and run the docker build command in powershell ?

Comment: Yes @samridhisachdeva, that is what I mean.

Comment: These errors are in the container.  Make sure you aren't connected to a VPN, and double check that you have the DNS configured for Docker, those both can lead to failures for your image to communicate to the outside world during your build.